# Angular Form merge data from select dropdown menus

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-forms, formarray, angular-formbuilder

How to merge values from dropdown menus into array of objects?
There are two dropdown menus (persons and countries) with pre populate values 
[image]

so when assigning country to person, I'm trying to get data in array of objects like: `[{person: 'John', country: 'USA'}, {person: 'Pablo', country: 'Mexico'}]` based on user selection.

I'm trying with `FormArray` but I'm doing something wrong

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-populate-values-jq6xya)**

Comment: A form array is used for the *ngFor. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530584/unable-to-create-the-dynamic-reactive-forms-using-angular/52531152#52531152 .

Comment: That's right, thanks. Is there a way to push all objects from form to array? It submits only last object https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-populate-values-jq6xya?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a formGroup to formArray base on the number of persons data so if you have two person you have to create two formGroup

like this

```
this.selectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  persons: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      'person': '',
      'country': ''
    }),
    this.formBuilder.group({
      'person': '',
      'country': ''
    })
  ])
});
```

or greate a formGroup base on the persons

```
this.selectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  persons: this.formBuilder.array(this.getFormGroupByN(this.personsData.length)
  )
});


getFormGroupByN(n: number) {
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      'person': '',
      'country': ''
    })
    );
  } // for end 

  return result;
}
```

I have create a variable to hold the persons data  caled `personsData` so Ican loop throw and create option element

```
this.personsData = this.parts.map(part => part.persons).reduce((r, part, []) => r.concat(part));
```

the result now look like this

```
[{"person":"John","country":"USA"},{"person":"Pablo","country":"Mexico"}]
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-populate-values-fixed)