# How do i initialize a formcontrol with an initial value, Validators.Required and disabled: true using FormBuilder?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl
I checked the FormControl page on the angular website to see if it had a constructor that allows me to set an initial value, disabled mode and a validator but it does not seem to have such a constructor. So my question is, is it possible to initialize a formcontrolname that has a value, is disabled and has Validators.required set?

This is what i tried so far:

```
this.temperatureSettingForm = fb.group({
  'country' : [{value: '', disabled: true},Validators.required],
  'cities' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'checkBox' : {value: false, disabled: true},
  'months': fb.group({
  'january' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'february' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'march' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'april' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'may' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'june' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'july' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'august' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'september' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'october' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'november' : {value: '', disabled: true},
  'december' : {value: '', disabled: true}
  })
});
```

Comment: Normally you can uase a function that received as argument the data and return a FormGroup, see, as e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530584/unable-to-create-the-dynamic-reactive-forms-using-angular/52531276#52531276

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yup, it does have such [constructor](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()):

```
country: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required)
```

Comment: it's not necesary using a constructor, just -if we have an object data with the property country- some like: country:[{data? data.country:'',disabled:true},Validators.required]